# Join Multiple Images IN FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

In VCL this is how i make a single image from two images while creating space between them:

```
 procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
p1,p2:string;
b1,b2:TBitmap;
bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
 p1:='C:\Users\John\Desktop\p1.bmp';
 p2:='C:\Users\John\Desktop\p2.bmp';
 b1:=TBitmap.Create;
 b1.LoadFromFile(p1);
 b2:=TBitmap.Create;
 b2.LoadFromFile(p2);
  sBit:= TBitmap.Create;
  try
   sBit.Height:=b1.Height;
   sBit.Width:=b1.Width+5+b2.Width;
   sBit.Canvas.Draw(0,0,b1); //Drawing First Bitamp here
   sBit.Canvas.Draw(b1.Width + 5,0,b2);// Drawing Second one 
   Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(sBit);
  finally
   sBit.FreeImage;
  end;
end;
```

Now How Can i draw the same in FMX ?

**EDIT**

**Using Bitmap.CopyFromBitmap Works!!**

```
 procedure process;
 var
  p1,p2: String;
  b1,b2,b3:TBitmaps;
  rect: TRect;
  begin
  //load both bitmaps to b1 and b2.
  rect.Left:=0;
  rect.Top:=0;
  rect.Width:=b1.Width;
  rect.Height:=b1.Height; 
  b3:= TBitmaps.Create;
  b3.Height:= b1.height;
  b3.widht:=b1.width;
  b3.CopyFromBitmap(b1,rect,0,0);
  b3.CopyFromBitmap(b2,rect,b1r.Width+5,0);
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(b3);
end;
```

Comment: The code in your edit doesn't compile because of problems addressed by @RemyLebeau . After corrections it compiles and work as said.

Comment: @TomBrunberg  Yeah Forgot to set Rects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VCL, you can't load a PNG image into a `TBitmap`, only a BMP image. You would have to use `TPngImage` instead for `b1` and `b2`.  `TPngImage` can be `Draw()`'n onto a VCL `TCanvas`.

FMX's `TBitmap` supports PNG, though.

In FMX, the equivalent of `Canvas.Draw()` in this situation would be to use [`TBitmap.CopyFromBitmap()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.CopyFromBitmap):

> Copies a rectangular area from a specified bitmap to the current bitmap.

And then use `Image1.Bitmap.Assign(sBit);` to assign the final `TBitmap` to the `TImage` (there is no `TPicture` in FMX).

Comment: i tried CopyFromBitmap but this is not loading anything to TImage please see my updated question.

Comment: @John you are not setting the dimensions of the destination `TBitmap` before calling `CopyFromBitmap()`, like you do in VCL before drawing. Also, you declared a separate `TRect` for `b2` but you are not actually using it. Your VCL code allows the two bitmaps to have different widths, but your FMX code does not. Also, there is no `TBitmaps`, it should be `TBitmap` instead. Also, you should not be using `GetCurrentDir()`, a process's CWD is dynamic and not guaranteed to be what you are expecting

Comment: Yeah Forgot to set Rects. was using same (br1) rect as both images have same dimes. it is `TBitmaps` beacause IDE can't resolve unit names, adding `FMX.Graphic.TBitmap` or `FMX.Graphic.Bitmap` to uses clause. and I didn't get the last part of your comment about `GetCurrentDir` sir, sorry.

Comment: @John there is no `TBitmaps` class. If your IDE can't resolve `TBitmap` then you need to fix your project. The correct unit name to put in the `uses` clause is `FMX.Graphics`.

Comment: It's already there `FMX.Graphics` but don't why it can't resolve `TBitmap` Unit.